# How to change default CSS File which is apply to the _Layout.cshtml using code in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

For eg:-In MVC Website the default css is Applyed "Site.css"
and I want to Apply "MyStlyle.css" inplace of "Site.css"...
How Can I change this File?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Root > App_Start > BundleConfig.cs

Change this line:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));
```

to

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/MyStlyle.css"));
```

And place your custom css in `Root/Content/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please give more specific information about your problem.
More-over, you can remove the default CSS from layout page and provide the CSS on the specific page you wish (i.e. on the local page)

or you can follow this approach:

> bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("your css");